# How to insert values into a REF and SET of REF in SQL ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I have problem with inserting values into tables with attributes that are REF and SET of REF of TYPES in SQL

I have tsportifs type :

```
create type tsportifs as object (
idsportif integer, 
nom varchar2(50), 
prenom varchar2(50),
sexe varchar2(50),
age integer
);
/
```

and tsport type :

```
create type tsport as object (idsport integer, libelle VARCHAR2(50));
/
```

and for the associations I have :

```
alter type tsportifs add attribute sportifs_sport t_set_ref_sport cascade;
alter type tsportifs add attribute sportifs_coneiller ref tsportifs cascade;
```

and for the tables :

```
create table sportifs of tsportifs (
    primary key(idsportif),
    CONSTRAINT chk_sexe CHECK (sexe IN ('F', 'M'))
    )nested table sportifs_sport store as table_sportifs_sport;
    
create table sport of tsport (primary key(idsport))nested table sport_sportifs store as table_sport_sportifs;
```

when I have tried to insert :

```
INSERT INTO Sportifs VALUES(1,'BOUTAHAR','Abderahim','M',30,REF(tsportifs(NULL)),REF(tsport(2)));
```

I get this error :

```
SQL> INSERT INTO Sportifs VALUES(1,'BOUTAHAR','Abderahim','M',30,REF(tsportifs(NULL)),REF(tsport(2)));
INSERT INTO Sportifs VALUES(1,'BOUTAHAR','Abderahim','M',30,REF(tsportifs(NULL)),REF(tsport(2)))
                                                                         *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

and I don't know how to insert multiple values into the nested table.

Answer (score 1):

Your DDL statements do not make sense as:

- You never define `t_set_ref_sport`; and
- The `sport` table is defined with a nested table but the type does not contain any collections.

Additionally, the `INSERT` statement does not makes sense (ignoring that it is syntactically invalid) as you have not `INSERT`ed any rows into `sport` for it to reference.

If you have the types:

```sql
CREATE TYPE tsport AS OBJECT(
  idsport integer,
  libelle VARCHAR2(50)
);

CREATE TYPE t_set_ref_sport IS TABLE OF REF TSPORT;

CREATE TYPE tsportifs AS OBJECT (
  idsportif          integer, 
  nom                varchar2(50), 
  prenom             varchar2(50),
  sexe               varchar2(50),
  age                integer,
  sportifs_coneiller REF tsportifs,
  sportifs_sport     t_set_ref_sport
);
```

then the tables:

```
create table sport of tsport (
  primary key(idsport)
);

create table sportifs of tsportifs (
  primary key(idsportif),
  CONSTRAINT chk_sexe CHECK (sexe IN ('F', 'M'))
)
nested table sportifs_sport store as table_sportifs_sport;
```

Then you can add scope constraints to the references:

```sql
ALTER TABLE sportifs ADD SCOPE FOR ( sportifs_coneiller ) IS sportifs;
ALTER TABLE table_sportifs_sport ADD SCOPE FOR ( COLUMN_VALUE ) IS sport;
```

And insert the data:

```sql
INSERT INTO sport (idsport, libelle) VALUES (2, 'Test');

INSERT INTO Sportifs (
  idsportif,
  nom,
  prenom,
  sexe,
  age,
  sportifs_coneiller,
  sportifs_sport
) VALUES (
  1,
  'BOUTAHAR',
  'Abderahim',
  'M',
  30,
  NULL,
  t_set_ref_sport(
    (SELECT REF(s) FROM sport s WHERE idsport = 2)
  )
);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1eInqJbq)

If you want a `NULL` reference then just insert `NULL`.

If you want to insert a reference to a row then use:

```sql
( SELECT REF(table_alias)
  FROM table_name table_alias
  WHERE primary_key_column = something )
```

If you want to insert a collection of references into a nested table then use:

```sql
collection_data_type(
  (SELECT REF(table_alias) FROM table_name table_alias WHERE primary_key_column = first_thing),
  (SELECT REF(table_alias) FROM table_name table_alias WHERE primary_key_column = third_thing),
  NULL,
  (SELECT REF(table_alias) FROM table_name table_alias WHERE primary_key_column = fourth_thing)
)
```